# Controllers for buttons in ionic

Tags: controller, ionic-framework

I've been running into some probelms with my controllers and I want to make sure I'm understanding them right.

I have two buttons that are suppose to link to their controllers

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn(user)">
  Sign-In
</button>
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signUp(user)">
  Sign-Up
</button>
```

and I have two controllers in my app.js

```
.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.signIn = function(user) {
        console.log('Sign-In', user);
        $state.go('welcome');
    };
})

.controller('SignUpCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.signUp = function(user) {
        console.log('Sign-In', user);
        $state.go('welcome');
    };
})
```

with the stateProvider being

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('signin', {
                url: '/sign-in',
                templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
                controller: 'SignInCtrl'
            })
            .state('welcome', {
                url: '/welcome',
                templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html'
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');
    })
```

Is their a reason the sign in button works and the sign up doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of the buttons are in sign-in.html, the problem is that in your app.js you have SignInCtrl listed as sign-in's controller and SignInCtrl does not contain the signUp() method.

If both buttons are on the same page, then why not add signUp() to SignInCtrl and remove the SignUpCtrl controller?

Answer (score 0):

These functions had the same `$state.go` so I changed one. I'm not sure it's in the way you wanted to worst case you can switch the two. In my mind this was a simple oversight ( ;

```
.controller('SignInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.signIn = function(user) {
        console.log('Sign-In', user);
        $state.go('signin');
    };
})

.controller('SignUpCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.signUp = function(user) {
        console.log('Sign-Up', user);
        $state.go('welcome');
    };
})
```